# Does OpenLayers3 support feature editing?

Tags: web-mapping, openlayers

For OpenLayers2, there are nice examples which show how to create vector features and edit them (adding vertices, moving them, ...), e.g. http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/modify-feature.html

Is it possible to reproduce this functionality in OpenLayers3? On the official website, I was only able to find an example which shows how to create vector features but not how to edit them: http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/draw-features.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism for modifying features in OpenLayers 3, similar to OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature in OpenLayers 2, has been added to the trunk and is called [ol.interaction.Modify](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html). Here is an [example of modifying features](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/modify-features.html?q=modify) only.

There is also a an example of combining [draw and modify](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html?q=modify) together, which uses an ol.FeatureOverlay, rather than ol.source.Vector, so that this can be passed to both the constructors for `ol.interaction.Modify` and `ol.interaction.Draw`, so that they can operate on the same vector objects and be simultaneously enabled. There is a method that looks for a <kbd>shift</kbd> press and single click to enable deleting a vertex.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have found the unfortunate answer that this is currently not possible:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ol3-dev/HP1by77TZJ0/qiVEaTCkf_EJ:

> On Mon, Jan 6, 2014 at 5:34 PM, Christophe Damour via OL3 Dev 
>   wrote:
>
> > Hi Eric,
> >
> > I gave a try to vector-api branch, and it looks great, but I got stuck 
> >     trying to add draw and modify interactions which doesn't seem to be 
> >     implemented in this branch :-)
> >
> > Is there an alternative ? Or have I missed something ?
>
> You haven't missed anything. This is currently under development.

Comment: http://ahocevar.github.io/ol3/edit/examples/modify-features.html at least has interesting implementation of topological polygon editing.

Comment: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/modify-features.html?q=modify It seems it has been added to the trunk.

Comment: @JohnBarça Feel free to post that as an answer

Comment: @underdark. Done. OL3 is starting to look really good.